# SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize version 4.3.0 on nodejs(v6.11.0) application having Mariadb (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.2
) on Ubuntu 16.04.
when application starts and calls function:
 `Sequelize.sync();`
Then sequelize connection manager throws following error:

> Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

```
at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:146:17)
at tryCatcher (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
at Async._drainQueue (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
at Async._drainQueues (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/home/dariksoft/cars/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

I updated mariadb-server and mariadb-client but the problem already exists!

Anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I found the answer:**

login to mysql command line and write the following commands:

```
use mysql;
```

`update user set authentication_string=password(''),plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';`

Comment: MySQL 8.0.11 with sql_mode=TRADITIONAL did not like the syntax.  The following worked without having to go to the system database, `alter user 'USER'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'PASSWORD'`.

Answer (score 3):

In case you are using higher versions of mysql, you don't need to use password function. Instead you can write it as below

```
use mysql;

update user set authentication_string='new_root_password', plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';

flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case I needed to type these 3 lines:

```
use mysql;
update user set authentication_string=password('new_root_password'), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
flush privileges;
```